# Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error while using malloc() and realloc()

Tags: c

Following is the piece of code where I am getting Signal 11 error while allocation of memory for the string which I want to return.

I will appreciate the help to pin-point where is the error and how do I fix it, thanks!

```
1265 static string encode_func(a_type_ptr ptr)
1266 {
1267   char *my_str=(char *)malloc(512);
//some variable declarations
 1275   int no_of_array_elements;
1276     while (field_ptr && field_ptr->type) {
1277         field_offset=field_ptr->offset*targ_char_bit;
1278         if (field_offset > current_offset) {
1279             if(sizeof(my_str) < (field_offset-current_offset)) {
1280                 my_str = (char*)realloc(my_str, (field_offset-current_offset+1));
1281             }
1282             for(int i = 0; i < (field_offset-current_offset); i ++) {
1283                 strcat(my_str, "X");
1284             }
1285         }
    //some condition check not relevant to memalloc'ed variables
1299         field_bit_size=get_field_bit_size(field_ptr);
1300         no_of_array_elements=field_bit_size/base_size;
1301         if (uptr != NULL) {
1302             string tmp = encode_func(uptr);
1303             char *sub_my_str = new char[tmp.size()];
1304             strncpy(sub_my_str, tmp.c_str(), sizeof(tmp));
1305             if(strlen(my_str) < strlen(sub_my_str)) {
1306                 char *tmp= (char *)realloc(my_str,((strlen(my_str)+no_of_array_elements*strlen(sub_my_str))+1));
1307                 if(tmp != NULL)
1308                     my_str = tmp;
1309             }
1310             strncat(my_str, sub_my_str, sizeof(sub_my_str));
1311             for(int i = 1; i < no_of_array_elements; i++) {
1312                 strncat(my_str, sub_my_str,sizeof(sub_my_str));
1313             }
1314         } else {
1315             char str[25];
1316             sprintf(str, "%ldo",  base_size);
1317             if(strlen(my_str) < (no_of_array_elements*strlen(str)))
1318             {
1319                 char *tmp = (char *)realloc(my_str,strlen(my_str)+no_of_array_elements*strlen(str)+1);
1320                 if(tmp!=NULL)
1321                     my_str =  tmp;
1322             }
1323             strncat(my_str,   str,strlen(str));
1324             for(int i = 1;  i < no_of_array_elements;   i++)
1325             {
1326                 strncat(my_str, str,strlen(str));
1327             }
1328         }
1329         current_offset=field_offset+field_bit_size;
1330         field_ptr=field_ptr->next;
1331     }
1332     struct_size=ptr->size*targ_char_bit;
1333     if(struct_size > current_offset) {
1334         if(strlen(my_str) < (struct_size-current_offset)) {
1335             char *tmp = (char *)realloc(my_str, (struct_size-current_offset+1));
1336             if(tmp != NULL)
1337                 my_str = tmp;
1338         }
1339         for(int i=0; i<(struct_size-current_offset); i++) {
1340             strcat(my_str, "X");
1341         }
1342     }
1343     my_str[strlen(my_str)] = '\0';
1344     string str_enc = string(my_str);
1345     return str_enc;
1346 }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Signal 11, code 1 (address not mapped to object)
(0)  0x4000000003039b00  term_on_signal + 0xa90 at host_envir.c:2129[./test]
(1)  0xe00000010d0028e0  ---- Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) delivered ----
(2)  0xc00000000023db70  real_malloc + 0x670 at ../../../../../core/libs/libc/shared_em_64/../core/gen/malloc.c:2748 [/usr/lib/hpux64/+++libc.so.1]
(3)  0xc00000000023cc80  _malloc + 0x140 at ../../../../../core/libs/libc/shared_em_64/../core/gen/malloc.c:1863 [/usr/lib/hpux64/libc+++.so.1]
(4)  0xc0000000002484b0  malloc + 0x140 at ../../../../../core/libs/libc/shared_em_64/../core/gen/malloc.c:5069 [/usr/lib/hpux64/libc.+++so.1]
(5)  0x40000000037de6d0  _Z11encode_funcP6a_type + 0x70 at test.C:1267 [./test]
(6)  0x40000000037de9e0  _Z11encode_funcP6a_type + 0x380 at test.C:1303 [./test]
(7)  0x40000000037de9e0  _Z11encode_funcP6a_type + 0x380 at test.C:1303 [./test]
```

Comment: Is this c or c++? Why did you tag it both?

Comment: Mangled symbols means C++, right?  Why is the tag C?

Comment: its a C++ file, but the code is in c(where error is )

Comment: The language doesn't usually change on a line-by-line basis.

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?  Did you pass meaningful values to `realloc()`?  You're certainly using it in a dangerous way.

Comment: The crash is occurring in `malloc()`, not `realloc()` as the title originally suggested.  A SIGSEGV in `malloc()` usually means that you (or your code) wrote outside the bounds of allocated memory, thereby corrupting the memory management data and triggering a memory fault (the code for `malloc()` wasn't expecting its data to be corrupted).  Use `valgrind` to find where you're going wrong.  Since this is C++ code according to the stack trace, you should consider why you're using `malloc()` and `realloc()` at all.  They are for C code, not C++ code.

Comment: `(sizeof(my_str) == sizeof (char*))` Also: the check for null return from realloc() ensures a memory overwrite at memory-full-time. Also: replace all the strncat() and strlen()s, and instead perform manual bookkeeping the used sizes. (IMHO)

Comment: @Jonathan: Actually initially code was in C++(with string objects used all over the places), but due to memory constraint for using string objects(as for large arrays it was going out of memory), I switched to char* string of C, and hence using malloc/realloc to form strings dynamically.

Comment: The space overhead of a C++ string is not great; you'll be running out of space with the C strings too.  Plus you've got to re-engineer the code to handle C strings accurately; in particular, you have to be dramatically more careful to ensure that the allocated space is released.  I don't think you made the correct trade-off.  What system are you running on that ran into problems?  Which C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: The other beautiful thing about memory corruption problems is that the code that does the damage is usually distant from the code that suffers from the damage.  It probably isn't this function that's at fault; it is probably some other code manipulating strings that is in trouble.  Does the code compile cleanly with no warnings when you turn on all the warnings?  (If you're using G++, then `g++ -Wall -Werror` is a starting point, but no guarantee.)

Comment: @Jonathan: I think compared to char strings, C++ string has more memory requirement as to store object itself(it does matter when we talk about very large strings). I also agree, with the efforts/care needed to do memory management in C manually, and hence I am stuck with that..but if done properly I am sure space requirement will be less and I could do some more optimizations(in terms of storing char in string in ASCII etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this program is to use the valgrind tool.

Comment: To clarify, if the crash is in `malloc` then the real error is somewhere else, and Valgrind helps you find where the real error is.

Comment: I am on HP-UX, and valgrind is not supported on it !! :(

Answer (score 1):

As bmargulies suggested, use Valgrind.
If you are on OS which does not support valgrind, I would suggest Purify, I don't believe there are any free solutions for non-Linux platforms.
If you can reproduce same issue on Windows, sprinkle your code with calls to _CrtCheckMemory, that will narrow down the problem - this isn't as good as Purify on Windows, but it's free.

Comment: I don't think valgrind is helpful here as I am working on HP-UX !

Does gdb have any support to do memory debugging ? If yes, how it can help in solving this issue?

Comment: I don't think gdb has anything that will help you. Look into Purify(from IBM)/Insure, but either of them are few thousand for Unix.  Depending on budget, and how you feel about it, you can just solve your issue by asking them for evaluation license.  In either case you have to call and talk, etc, etc. it's not a simple download - at least wasn't years ago when I did it (we ended up with Purify because of lower cost).

Comment: You can try sprinkling your code with calls to malloc, to try and narrow down the problem. That's the only other solution I can think of in terms of debugging.  There's always rewriting parts of code, or just re-reading them, or getting a tool to analyze memory, or heck even writing your own basic malloc/free - which allocates extra bytes before and after each buffer, and periodically scanning those bytes for changes.